# google image search api limit

Tags: google-image-search

I am writing a Java application that needs to get images from Google image search (or similar).

It works as simple as a web call:
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=japan

However, the response is limited to 8 results per page.
and google search is free for only 100 requests per day, so 800 results per day.

Is that correct?

Comment: I would like to suggest that it would be a good idea to make your own cache of google maps images. I'm doing that by simply running the MD5 Function on the address and storing that as the filename. This would reduce the number of actual requests to google, and would increase the speed of your application. Food for thought.

Comment: Well if you need unlimited images searches on Google.
You can try https://serpapi.com/images-results This web service will return a nice standardize json with all the images in your query. The service is also integrate to most of popular programming languages: python, java, nodes, golang, ruby...

Comment: Serapi is a paid service, and actually now expensive than Google API. ($50 per month for 130 queries per day)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The replacement for that deprecated API is here: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview and for billing they note:

> Any usage beyond the free usage quota will fail if you are not signed up for billing. Once you have enabled billing, you will continue to receive 100 free queries per day. However, you will be billed for all additional requests at the rate of $5 per 1000 queries, for up to 10,000 queries per day.

So the alternative is, simply, to pay for what you need.

There is lots of information from a similar question here: [What's the best web image search API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533857/whats-the-best-web-image-search-api)

Somebody on that thread notes:

> As of August 2012, Bing API will be part of Azure Marketplace: free access still available, but limited to a number of queries (5000/month). Google limits the free access to 100 queries/day.

So perhaps Bing has sufficient free quota for your needs? There are other options on that page also, check it out.

Comment: Link to custom-search overview is broken. Maybe this is the new link: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/overview

Comment: Actually, that root docs folder eventually leads to the broken link provided in this answer. [This location](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview) describes the JSON API, the query limit and costs, and the steps to get it set up.